# Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu 16.04.02 no sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I feel like I've tried all the answers but no luck in solving the problem. I fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS from Windows 8 initially. Everything was working fine except sound, which does't work at all. This is the output of aplay -l

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Only HDA Intel HDMI is detected, and I've no idea why. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, just flashed the newer BIOS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Resetting BIOS to factory defaults should be enough (flashing BIOS will probably same effect).